# Which REST HTTP status code is used when the body data is the same as the current state in the database?

Tags: rest, http, http-status-codes

Which http status code would be appropriate if a user sends a request to update some data, but the request body and the database data are identical?

For example, let's assume there is a boolean column called **is_active** in the database set as **true**. A user sends an http request to toggle that value from true to true.

Is there a status code that can indicate to the client that the request did not fail, but there were no changes to the database?

Answer (score 2):

> Which http status code would be appropriate if a user sends a request to update some data, but the request body and the database data are identical?

[200 OK](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.1).  In some specific circumstances, [204 No Content](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.5).

> Is there a status code that can indicate to the client that the request did not fail, but there were no changes to the database?

No, because that's not a concern we have in the "transferring documents over a network" domain.

If you have a bespoke client that cares about that sort of information, present it to the client in the message-body of the response, as part of the [representation of the status of the action](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.1).